# Library specific iTunes preferences?

Tags: itunes, preferences

I would like to have two iTunes libraries with one being automatically organized and the other letting me choose where to store the files. When I create a second library it seems to share the same preferences as the first (the settings are actually iTunes preferences). Is it possible to have separate settings for my libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iTunes preferences are stored in

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iTunes.plist
```

I presume you access your two libraries by launching iTunes while holding down the <kbd>Opt</kbd> key.

An alternate method to launch iTunes and swap out pref files at the same time would be to make an Automator or AppleScript app that switches pref files, and makes a link from `~/Music/iTunes` to one of the libraries, then launches iTunes for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an Apple Script someone wrote to solve a similar problem, be sure to read their situation and change the script for your needs:
http://forums.macnn.com/82/applications/358119/itunes-applescript-question/